# How to see full Status Detail of Apex Job

Tags: scheduled-apex, debugging, logging

I have an apex job that is failing with a null pointer exception.  The status detail unfortunately cuts the stacktrace just short of where it is actually helpful.  Is there anyway to view the full stacktrace?  Or a way to pull up a debug log for the entire Apex job?

[image]

Comment: the CCC Admin user didn't get an email with the full status?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setup a debug log by going to Monitoring->Debug Logs under the name which this job runs (listed under the 'Monitored Users'). Next time when the job runs, you should see a full log with complete stack trace along with any debug statements (listed under the 'Debug Logs'). Note that there is a limit on the size of these logs - typically triggers and other web services do not cross these limits, but scheduled jobs may cross depending upon the volume of the records/data it is processing, in which case, the logs will be truncated right at where the size reaches the limits.

Comment: So I can't set up the logs to monitor only a specific job?  I have to set it up to monitor all the user actions?

Comment: You set the monitoring by user name, but the log will appear per execution context. For e.g. if you have a scheduled job run under your name and at the same time you access a VF page that invokes a trigger then you will see two different log entries, each will have logs pertaining to that particular execution.

Comment: OK... yea i get it.  I guess the problem is that it is happening somewhere in a Batch job.  I actually found the bug already but was hoping to find a better solution for future debugging.